# Why can't I see the files my code has uploaded to Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have code that uses the Google Drive v3 SDK.

I have a regular (free) Gmail account, and have created a service account. I created a folder in my Google Drive space and shared it with the service account. Lots of kudos to [Linda Lawton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto), whose tutorials are waaay better than the Google docs!

My code uses the Id of the shared folder as its root, and can upload files to the folder and download them again. However, if I look in Google Drive in my browser when signed in with my regular account, the shared folder is empty.

When I upload files, I set a permission of `anyone` for the `Reader` role, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Can anyone explain why I can't see the files? I know that the service account has its own GD space, but I'm using the shared folder, which is in my GD space, not the service account's, so I expected to see the files.

**Update** I'm pretty sure the problem is that the permissions are not being set correctly on the files. I'm doing the following...

```cs
Permission permission = new() { Role = "reader", Type = "anyone" };
await _service.Permissions.Create(permission, fileId);
```

Note that this uses the .NET SDK, but I don't think that should make a lot of difference, the code is almost identical in (say) Java.

I added a call to query the permissions on a file that my script had uploaded, and got the following two...

```
  Type: anyone, Role: reader, Kind: drive#permission, Email:
  Type: user, Role: owner, Kind: drive#permission, Email:
```

The first permission comes from the code shown above. The second one is from when I tried setting a permission for the Gmail account. It seems to have set the permission, but not stored the email address.

Either way, I would have expected that the first permission would have been enough to allow the Gmail account to see them from a browser.

Thanks

Comment: For example, in order to replicate your situation, can you provide your script for uploading the file?

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry for the delay in replying. I updated the question, as I think I've narrowed down the issue to the permissions, and have shown the code I'm using to set a permission on the newly-uploaded file. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, in your situation, after the file was uploaded with your script, when you check the permission of the uploaded file, what value will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike Please see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your showing permission, in this case, your account is not included? I think that in your situation, the owner of the uploaded file is the service account. So, in this case, in order to see the uploaded file in the specific folder of your Google Drive, how about sharing the uploaded file to your Google account?

Comment: For example, about `I created a folder in my Google Drive space and shared it with the service account.`, if this folder is shared with the service account as the writer, when you don't use your script for creating the permission just after the file is uploaded, what result will you obtain? Because, in this case, you have the permission as a writer. But, if I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike _From your showing permission, in this case, your account is not included?_ No, I tried setting a permission that allowed anyone to read the file, which I thought would be enough. I tried adding a permission to allow the Gmail account to see the file, but couldn't get this to work. That's partly what I'm asking in this question.

Comment: @Tanaike _I think that in your situation, the owner of the uploaded file is the service account._ Yes. _So, in this case, in order to see the uploaded file in the specific folder of your Google Drive, how about sharing the uploaded file to your Google account?_ That's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to set a permission on the file so that the Gmail account can see it. I've done this on another project and it worked fine, although that Gmail account was a paid-for domain account, and the permission was a domain permission. I want to know how to do it for a regular Gmail account.

Comment: Thank you for replying. 1. About `I tried adding a permission to allow the Gmail account to see the file, but couldn't get this to work.`, I think that in your situation, when the file is uploaded, the permission of the uploaded file includes your account as the writer. How about this? If you have already had the permission, I thought that you can see it at your Drive. 2. About `Gmail account was a paid-for domain account`, in your current situation, the service account is created in `Gmail account was a paid-for domain account`?

Comment: @Tanaike Not sure what you mean by your first point. I already updated my question to show what permissions a typical file has. As for the second point, the current situation does **NOT** use a paid-for domain account, it uses a regular free Gmail account. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `Not sure what you mean by your first point.`, I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. I have to study English more. About `I already updated my question to show what permissions a typical file has. As for the second point, the current situation does NOT use a paid-for domain account, it uses a regular free Gmail account. Thanks`, from this, I would like to try to understand your situation. When I could correctly understand it and find the solution, I would like to post the answer.

Comment: @Tanaike No problem about the English, I really appreciate your help! Please let me know exactly what you don't understand, and I'll explain.

Comment: @Tanaike Any chance you could explain what you still don't understand? Thanks again

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? By this, I thought that it will help users think of the reason for your current issue. Because, unfortunately, I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my English. So, I thought that in this case, providing the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation might help users to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor English slill again. I would like to study more.

Comment: @Tanaike I finally found the problem, which was not something you'd likely have known from the information I gave. Please see my answer. Thanks very much for all the help you gave me, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many hours of banging my head against the screen, I finally realised that when I created the top-level folder, I forgot to specify the shared folder, so my code was creating its folders and files in the service account's drive space, not in the shared folder.

I set the correct parent folder, and all works fine now! Don't know if this will ever help anyone, but I'll leave the question and this answer in case it does.